# Why are integral operators defined the way they are?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

I'm reading a book on functional analysis, in which the following example is given after the definition of an operator.

> Let $-\infty<a<b<\infty$, and let the function $F:[a,b]\times[a,b]\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. We set
>
> $$(Au)(x) = \int_a^x F(x,y,u(y))dy~~~\forall~x\in[a,b]$$
>
> $$(Bu)(x) = \int_a^b F(x,y,u(y))dy~~~\forall~x\in[a,b]$$
>
> Then, we obtain the two operators $A:C[a,b] \to C[a,b]$ and $B:C[a,b]\to C[a,b]$. The operators $A$ and $B$ are called integral operators.

1. How did the author jump to the fact that if $u$ is continuous, then so are $Au$ and $Bu$? There's no justification given in any of the prior sections.
2. **Why** is this example important at all? The way $F$ is defined seems so arbitrary. Why not instead define $F:[a,b]\times[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ and include $F(x,y)$ in the integral? Wouldn't that be simpler? Why take the limits $a$ to $b$ in the expression for $Bu$? What's the motivation/justification of defining this stuff the way it is? I'm asking because these operators seem important enough to have a name.

Comment: Should the definition of $Bu$ have $\int_a^b$ with no $x$? The definition of $Au$ has $x$ as a bound.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but that's how it's stated in the book. I'm assuming $x$ will come out of $F$, since it's not integrated over.

Comment: That should be $B:C[a,b]\to \mathbb R.$

Comment: These are functional operators. They take as input a function $u$ of a single argument and output another function. Hence $u$ needs to appear in the definition.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thanks, but I'm aware of that. That's not what was confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first point is just a simple fact about the Riemann integral. If you know the dominated convergence theorem you can prove it very easily, but here is a proof that avoids that machinery.

Since $u$ is continuous, $u([a,b]) \subseteq [c,d]$ for some $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, $F$ is continuous on the compact set $[a,b]\times[a,b]\times[c,d]$ and hence is bounded there, say $F([a,b]\times[a,b]\times[c,d]) \subseteq [-C,C]$. So $$|Au(x_1) - Au(x_2)| \leq \bigg | \int_{x_1}^{x_2} |F(x,y,u(y))| dy \bigg | \leq C |x_1 - x_2|.$$

Continuity of $B$ can be established similarly, using uniform continuity of $F$ in the first variable on $[a,b]\times[a,b]\times[c,d]$.

These operators are actually incredibly important (although often we want a larger domain than $C[a,b]$, but that should give motivation to study the nice case of continuous functions).

For example, the definition hides it a bit, but you're quite possibly actually already familiar with very useful examples of such operators. The usual [integral transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform) (Fourier, Laplace etc.) are examples of integral operators.

Even if you don't care about these specific integral operators, you'll often find such operators cropping up as energy functionals in [Calculus of Variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) problems which alone is a good enough reason to care about them.